# How to make bookmark that can be made in evernote chrome extention

Tags: python, bookmarks, evernote

I'm now making the program that when I give URL, it reads URL, show bookmark using og tag, and then give it to EVERNOTE

SO I'm now researching on EVERNOTE API, But I can't find the URL bookmarker function that I can make. I'm expecting that this function would be available because there is the function in the Evernote google extentions. [This is the example of the evernote google extentions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhIHN.png)
If you know any ways to make that url book marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for but the list of APIs in the [reference](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/) is all you can use. The Evernote extension, which I assume Evernote Web Clipper, also uses those APIs under the hood. You should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).